# How to select nearest feature with the same attribute on different layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, proximity, virtual-layer

**Introduction:** I have two point data sets containing data about sites investigated using different methods, let's call them *sites-original* and *sites-comparison*. Each table has a field "method" stating the investigation method used on the site as a string (standardized e.g. always 'Method A', 'Method B' etc.).

**Problem**: For each feature from the layer *sites-original* I need to select the nearest feature from the layer *sites-comparison* that has the same value in the field "method", e.g. I want to be able to compare a site from *sites-original* on which 'Method A' was used to the closest site from *sites-comparison* on which 'Method A' was used, but I want each site only to appear ones in the data set. E.g. when a feature from *sites-comparison* has already been selected as suitable for one feature from *sites-original* it should not be used again for a different site.

**Attempt at solution**: By combining filters with the tool `Join attributes by nearest` I was able to create a new layer which contains the ID and name of the nearest feature from *sites-comparison*, however, since the sites sometimes cluster, I get the same nearest comparison site for several of the original sites. I tinkered a bit with a virtual layer, but I don't have much experience there and did not get useful results.